# Can I avoid __device__ qualifier when calling a function on the GPU?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Functions that will be run on the GPU need the qualifier `__device__`. I'm currently writing a general set of mathematical functions, which can be used on the GPU as well as on the CPU. I think it's not very nice to qualify all those functions as `__device__` since they might also be included into other programs where no CUDA is present at all. Is there a way to leave out the `__device__`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just compile with `-D__device__=""` when building for a non-CUDA target, or perhaps use a more general-purpose macro which can be defined as `__device__` when compiling for CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef __CUDACC__
#define __device__
#endif
```

Or similar. Of course, you would need similar guards to deal with includes and functions that *don't* make sense in a non-CUDA setting.